# I want to develop a Visual Studio extension,like TypeScript extension

Tags: visual-studio

I want to develop a Visual Studio extension,
Features a bit like TypeScript extension,
On TypeScript, after writing the .ts file, the system automatically generates the corresponding .js file.

And my idea is similar, written .tcs file, the system automatically generates the corresponding .cs file.
In this way, the code can complete aop, you can also optimize the extra performance of the ORM plug-in

that uses LINQ expressions.

Now the problem is:
I do not know what I need dll files and interfaces,
Also do not know whether to inherit the CSharp editor to achieve .tcs file editing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can utilize a [T4 Text Template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) to generate your .cs file instead of writing an extension.